# Regex transform list of nations into a regex search

Tags: javascript, regex

**What I'm trying to do:**
I'm using datatables (http://www.datatables.net/), an awesome jQuery plugin for html tables. There is also a search field where I can use regexp to filter the list of options and it works great. This search:  (^sweden$)|(^united kingdom$) filters the list and only shows records connected to theese two countries. But I don't think a user should have to know regexp so I'm trying to allow a user to input sweden, united kingdom, and on key up convert it to a regexp search inside a hidden field :)
I've manaded to get the list from , to | and it removes any accidental double comma (,,) or multiple spaces, but I'm a bit stuck as to how to capture each country and add the (^$) around it in output.

**CODE:**

```
var countryFilterUserInput = $("#colCountry_filterUser").val();
var countryFilterUserInput = countryFilterUserInput.replace(/[, ]* *,+ *([^((,| )+$)])/g,"|$1").replace(/[, ]*$/,'');
console.log(countryFilterUserInput);
```

Input: `sweden, united kingdom`

gives me `sweden|united kingdom`

I'm trying to make it: `(^sweden$)|(^united kingdom$)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply  replace commas:

```
var regex = "(^"+ countryFilterUserInput.replace(/\s*,\s*/g, "$)|(^")+"$)";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a non-capturing group so you don't need to add the start and end characters in every option. Try this:

```
var countries = 'sweden, united kingdom'.split(/,\s?/);
var regex = new RegExp('^(?:'+ countries.join('|') +')$');
```

Comment: I tried both, and I couldn't get the result from this one to trigger the correct search. (and of course I replaced the text string with input from textfield ^__^)